# Better to hack restful authentication or swap out to something newer like AuthLogin or Warden/Devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, plugins, authlogic, restful-authentication

I've got a rails app with a functioning restful_authentication system but I need to add password reset (never got around to it before...). Also I'm going to be probably adding things like invitations and some features that don't require login. And to be honest I was never completely happen with the way that restful authentication invaded my code.

If I stick with restful authentication I'll need to snarf in some unofficial forgot password code from a forum or blog, which could be a bit risky in terms of having to write my own tests etc. On the other hand, if I upgrade, that means possibly more work and exposure from switching away from what's tested and working in my app. (It might also matter that I'm planning on allowing facebook authentication in the future.)

I often have this kind of quandary with Rails apps because the ecosystem moves so fast, so I'm also interested in what people think about this problem in general. With a "legacy" rails app, do you patch & upgrade old plugins or swap them out for newer sexier ones?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can upgrade to devise/authlogic and leave the password database field remains. Devise and authlogic has a built-in plugin to read from restful_auth password field.

Comment: So would you actually recommend I do that?

Comment: Both approach would have same amount of efforts. Devise support for Rails 2 has stopped lately. So is authlogic. I would try to hack the current restful_auth and and the same time change to a newer solution and see which one works for your needs. I would then decide from there.

Answer (score 0):

I usually opt for upgrading as quickly as possible, especially if there is considerable future development planned. Once you fall too far behind, upgrading only gets more painful.